# Filter a list based on a parameter

Tags: scala

I want to filter the employees based on name and return the id of each employee

```
case class Company(emp:List[Employee])
  case class Employee(id:String,name:String)

  val emp1=Employee("1","abc")
  val emp2=Employee("2","def")

  val cmpy= Company(List(emp1,emp2))

  val a = cmpy.emp.find(_.name == "abc")
  val b = a.map(_.id)
  val c = cmpy.emp.find(_.name == "def")
  val d = c.map(_.id)

  println(b)
  println(d)
```

I want to create a generic function that contains the filter logic and I can have different kind of list and filter parameter for those list

Ex `employeeIdByName` which takes the parameters

**Updated**

- criteria for filter `eg :_.name and id`
- list to filter `eg:cmpy.emp` value
- for comparison `eg :abc/def`

Any better  way  to achieve the result 
I have used `map` and `find`

Comment: Try the filter function. I'm not sure what the 'for comparison' means. Isn't that just the criteria for the filter?

Answer (score 1):

**If** you really want a "generic" filter function, that can filter any list of elements, by any property of these elements, based on a closed set of "allowed" values, while mapping results to some other property - it would look something like this:

```
def filter[T, P, R](
    list: List[T],          // input list of elements with type T (in our case: Employee)
    propertyGetter: T => P, // function extracting value for comparison, in our case a function from Employee to String
    values: List[P],        // "allowed" values for the result of propertyGetter
    resultMapper: T => R    // function extracting result from each item, in our case from Employee to String
): List[R] = {
  list
    // first we filter only items for which the result of 
    // applying "propertyGetter" is one of the "allowed" values:
    .filter(item => values.contains(propertyGetter(item)))
    // then we map remaining values to the result using the "resultMapper"
    .map(resultMapper)
}

// for example, we can use it to filter by name and return id:
filter(
  List(emp1, emp2), 
  (emp: Employee) => emp.name, // function that takes an Employee and returns its name
  List("abc"), 
  (emp: Employee) => emp.id // function that takes an Employee and returns its id
)
// List(1)
```

**However**, this is a ton of noise around a very simple Scala operation: **filtering** and **mapping** a list; This specific usecase can be written as:

```
val goodNames = List("abc")
val input = List(emp1, emp2)

val result = input.filter(emp => goodNames.contains(emp.name)).map(_.id)
```

Or even:

```
val result = input.collect {
  case Employee(id, name) if goodNames.contains(name) => id
}
```

Scala's built-in `map`, `filter`, `collect` functions are already "generic" in the sense that they can filter/map by any function that applies to the elements in the collection.

Comment: Thks can u explain ur code .I want to return id of employee.my bad I will update the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shapeless. If you have a `employees: List[Employee]`, you can use

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.record._

employees.map(LabelledGeneric[Employee].to(_).toMap)
```

To convert each `Employee` to a map from field key to field value. Then you can apply the filters on the map.